# Why is the While loop creating a syntax error on the next statement

Tags: python, while-loop

Hi I've been trying to write a program in python 2.7 that takes a word as its input and outputs the number of letters in a word. At first it was working but something happened and now it keeps returning an error by the first line that is not part of the while loop.
This is a part of the code:

```
def number_of_letters(input):
    nol = input.find(input[-1])
    while input[nol:] != input[-1]:
        nol = input.find(input[-1], input.find(input[-1] + 1)
    nol = nol + 1
    print nol
```

The python interpreter keeps returning a syntax error by whatever I try to put after the while block (in this case 'nol = nol + 1 ') 
I've tried playing around with it but nothing worked. PLease help.
By the way if there are any modules that may help with this program that would be great but I'd also like to know why this one isn't working

Comment: In the future, it would be great to include what the SyntaxError is in the question. Also what line it's on. My interpreter says the SyntaxError is on line 5 -- and so I examined that line and the line before. Looks like you are missing a closing parenthesis on the line in the `while` loop.

Comment: Mine did not say what line it was- it kept varying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren:

```
nol = input.find(input[-1], input.find(input[-1] + 1)) #<- add here
```

If you want to count the number of actual letters you can use `str.isalpha`:

```
return sum(ch.isalpha() for ch in inp)
```

If you don't care what characters are there just use `len(inp)`.

Avoid `input` as a variable name as it shadows the python function.

Comment: It worked thanks btw I hate typos

Comment: @JediPythonClone, no worries, it happens ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
nol = input.find(input[-1], input.find(input[-1] + 1)
```

to this

```
nol = input.find(input[-1], input.find(input[-1] + 1))
```

Notice that parenthesis in the end.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked btw typos suck

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in function for getting the length of a string in python.

```
word = "test"
length = len(word)
```

Comment: The OP is probably just trying to create their own function for a reason of their own.

Comment: He also asked for any "modules" that would help.